# jQuery Recalculate Keyboard Tab When Revealed

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I've created a Gravity Form that has one visible field. When the user begins typing, the container expands to reveal additional fields.

It works great, but when you hit the "Tab" button on the keyboard, it jumps to a different form. My guess is that this is being caused by hiding the form, so when it's revealed the browser isn't be told to recalculate the tab increment.

Is there such a jQuery function or something I can add so that it recalculates within my keydown function?

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
// Home CTA Animation
if (windowWidth > 1024) {
$('#gform_9').css({
  'will-change' : 'height',
  'transition' : 'all 0.75s',
  'height' : '70px',
  'overflow' : 'hidden'
  });

$('#gform_9').one('keydown', function() {

        $('#gform_9').css({
          'height' : '560px',
          'overflow' : 'visible'
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Googling "gravity forms tab key" gives a bunch of promising results.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even realize it didn't calculate the tab index automatically, here I was thinking it was done by the browser ><

Comment: In the absence of `tabindex` attributes the browser follows a "natural" order. I would guess that Gravity Forms imposes a `tabindex` order but not dynamically, therefore things can go wrong.